# So what's the community feeling on someone posting a "review X game (I made) for me" kind of question?  

Tags: discussion

As was mentioned in a few questions, it's crucial to get good advice/input/feedback on your game.

Given the structure of SE sites, I think it would make the most sense if the question was slanted at reviewing a particular aspect with a particular goal, i.e.

BAD: "review my game"
GOOD: "please comment on the colour scheme used in the buttons on this screen: ..."

... albeit this is not as useful as a whole random "what do you like and not like" question (which is too broad and too hard to pick a "best answer" for).

What's your take on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So what's the community feeling on someone posting a "review X game (I made) for me" kind of question?

Such a question is a lot like ["Best" questions](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/best-best-bessssssst-argh/647#647): fundamentally not answerable.

A review is by definition an opinion. It can be based on facts, but it is ultimately what someone thinks. SE sites are not discussion forums, and if that's all gamedev.se is going to be, we may as well close it now and move to gamedev.net.

Stack Exchange is not for everything. And one of those "everythings" that it is not for is reviews.

Comment: I agree with this.  If you really want to get feedback on your game from this community, ask in the chat, there might be a few people willing to give your game a shot.

Comment: Even then, wouldn't gaming's chat be slightly more suitable for that?

Comment: They're both good places to ask for a game review, the gaming chat would probably be a good test of "do gamers like it", the gamedev chat might focus a bit more on some of the elements of the game, or they might provide a bit more insight on *why* something in the game is good or bad.  I'd probably try to get feedback in both places (and maybe hit up one of the UI/graphic design chat rooms for feedback on that part)

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more suited on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), though it'll still be somewhat off-topic. I agree chat would be a very good option.